# Webix load combo get all values into array

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, webix

I'm loading some data into a hidden Webix combo box via URL with two parameters. After loading, I want to store all values from the combo box into an array. But this doesn't work. If it is possible to load data from URL to an array without loading it first into a combo, how does this work? I use Spring ResourceMapping annotation in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [webix DataCollection](https://docs.webix.com/api__refs__datacollection.html) which work as any webix data component but without any graphical representation :

```
var store = new webix.DataCollection({ url:"data.php" });
```

Another solution is to manually do [ajax request](https://docs.webix.com/helpers__ajax_operations.html) :

```
webix.ajax().get('data.php', function(txt, data) { console.log(data.json()); });
```